# How to restrict XML Eternal Entity Reference when using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack, veracode

I am trying to resolve a vulnerability found in a Veracode scan. The problem appears to be our use of [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). The error reported by Veracode is

> Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference ('XXE')

Below is a sample of the way we are using HtmlAgilityPack. I cannot see any way to disallow external entity references. Does anyone have a suggestion for this? Thank you.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlString);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that HtmlAgilityPack does anything with an entity as shown on the [Wikipedia XML external entity attack page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_external_entity_attack). Can you get it to do so? Can Veracode themselves? I can't.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I’m still looking into it. Thanks for the direction.